# Using Sort in VBA for a Range that Changes

Tags: excel, function, vba, sorting, range

I have a range of cells in VBA that changes each time the code is run. I am trying to write code so that this range is sorted by column F.

The problem I am having is that it can only be this specific range of cells. There are other cells underneath this range that I do not want sorted, and this range changes in size. Part of the code is below. This is what I have tried so far with no luck.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

vtools = Selection

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exceptions Weekly Summary").Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
    :=Range(vtools), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exceptions Weekly Summary").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B11:H14")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

This does not work.

I cannot directly reference the cells (I cannot use Range("F2:F5") for example) because these cells are in different places each time the code is run. I know how to find what I need sorted, and even select it, but I am having trouble telling the sort function which column to sort by.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: *I know how to find what I need sorted, and even select it* Which lines in the current code do this? (I'm guessing the first two lines) And will this selection then be the "B11:H14" that is currently hard-coded in your `.Sort`?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, the first two lines in the code do this. Range B11 to H14 are the ranges selected in the particular code that I copied, but this will change each time the code is run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly this will help. It finds out the row numbers of the selected area and then makes a range in column F with these numbers and uses this as the key for ordering.

```
Sub sortOnlySelectedArea()

Dim actSheet As Worksheet
Dim upper, lower As Integer
Dim tempString As String
Dim selectedArea As Range

Set actSheet = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' here you have to put in your part to make the right selection
actSheet.Range("E5:G6").Select
Set selectedArea = Selection

upper = selectedArea.Row
lower = upper + selectedArea.Rows.Count - 1

tempString = "F" & CStr(upper) & ":F" & CStr(lower)
actSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
actSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tempString), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With actSheet.Sort
    .SetRange selectedArea
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly, with a few modifications. Instead of using the actSheet variable, I just used ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("(Name of Sheet)"). Greatly appreciated.