# "Runtime error 1004: Sort reference not valid"

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I copied some code from this site that I thought would solve a problem I was trying to solve. I copied the original code from [Using Sort in VBA for a Range that Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174908/using-sort-in-vba-for-a-range-that-changes)
I made very little in the way of changes just defining the top left of the data as being in cell A3. The final code ran as follows:

```
Sub sortOnlySelectedArea()
   Dim actSheet As Worksheet
   Dim upper, lower As Integer
   Dim tempString As String
   Dim selectedArea As Range
   Set actSheet = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   ' here you have to put in your part to make the right 
   'actSheet.Range("E5:G6").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("a3").CurrentRegion.Select
   Set selectedArea = Selection
   upper = selectedArea.Row
   lower = upper + selectedArea.Rows.Count - 1
   tempString = "F" & CStr(upper) & ":F" & CStr(lower)
   actSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
   actSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(tempString), _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
   DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With actSheet.Sort
       .SetRange selectedArea
       .Header = xlGuess
       .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
   End With
End Sub
```

My problem is that the code fails almost at the end. I have stepped through the code and it is picking up the data area correctly. It fails when it reaches The last but one line ( .Apply) which is then is highlighted. The debug message indicates Runtime error 1004: Sort reference not valid.
I cannot follow the code well enough to see how the sort range is selected. Ideally I would like to be able to sort on column C but would settle for column A if necessary. The range I am trying to sort is A3:F105.

Comment: Given that you are using Range.CurrentRegion do you have any blank rows/columns within A3:F105?  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214248%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is more of what you need...

```
Sub someSortRoutine()
   Dim sortsheet As Worksheet
   Dim sortArea As Range
   Dim keyColumn As Range

   Set sortsheet = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")       
   Set sortArea = sortsheet.Range("a3").CurrentRegion
   Set keyColumn = Application.Intersect(sortsheet.Range("F:F"), sortArea)

   sortsheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
   sortsheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=keyColumn, _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
   DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With sortsheet.Sort
       .SetRange sortArea
       .Header = xlGuess
       .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. With the help of all of three responders I have gained a big step forward in my experience of not only sorting but also range definition, And I can adapt this to a little project I have abandoned a couple of times previously due to my lack of experience

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate runtime error 1004 when my region didn't include any data in column F.

The line

```
tempString = "F" & CStr(upper) & ":F" & CStr(lower)
```

is determining the sorting column.  If you change the F to A I think that would sort it on column A.

Comment: You were spot on. I have realized how simple (and stupid) was my mistake. I thought when I had copied the original code that I had corrected it enough to solve my problems. I thank you and the other 2 responders for what has been an exremely useful learning experience which will help me in handling sorting and range selection in the future

Answer (score 0):

I will take for granted that you know how a [CurrentRegion Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214248%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) represents an island of data around a specified cell or cells. The success of your sorting operation will depend on that.

The most obvious potential conflict to my eyes is telling *actSheet* to represent *Sheet1* but subsequently telling *actSheet* to sort the selected current region on on the `ActiveSheet`. These are not necessarily the same worksheet.

The following attempts to consolidate the references to the worksheets while using an alternative coding method for the actual sort routine.

```
Sub sortOnlySelectedArea()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a3").CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(6), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

The name of that sub is deceiving in that your original selected the `.CurrentRegion` around the active worksheet's A3 cell but it does the same thing. As mentioned, there is some confusion around the `ActiveSheet` and `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. You need to pick one method of referencing and stick with it. Bouncing back and forth can only lead to conflicts that may not reproduce themselves all of the time (e.g. only when Sheet1 is *not* the active worksheet).

Lastly, it is never a good idea to let Excel *guess* whether you have a header row or not. You should know if you do or not.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand all the comments. As an amateur it helps me tremendously by having my misconceptions sorted. With the help of yourself and the other 2 posts I have understood a lot about sorting data and range selection that have fooled me in the past. Happily my problem is solved and can approach any future such problems myself